# GmailApp htmlBody error on format table html with createTemplateFromFile and getContent()

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

i'm trying to send a email from google sheet, i want to make a simple table (no CSS or FancyStuf) in html with the data, but when i create the draft in GmailApp, this table come with a lot of  "& nbsp;" and i have no idea where this come from, make the table totally useless for my purpose.

the code i use is

```js
var AS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var UltimoRegistro = AS.getRange("B15:B").getValues().filter(String).length;
var datos = AS.getRange(14, 1,UltimoRegistro+1,18).getValues()
var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Correo');
t.data = datos;
var output = t.evaluate()
var output2 = output.getContent()
Logger.log(output2)
GmailApp.createDraft('testmail@gmail.com', 'prueba','',{htmlBody:output2} )
//for testing purpose
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, "titulo")
```

Correo.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div>
  <body>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

The result i get on Logger.log are:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div>
  <body>
    <table>
              <tr>
                      <td>PM</td>
                      <td>FUNCIONAL </td>
                      <td>TIPO</td>
                      <td>PROYECTO</td>
                      <td>E4E</td>
                      <td>SAP</td>
                      <td>DESCRIPCION</td>
                      <td>UN</td>
                      <td>CANTIDAD</td>
                      <td>OBSERVACIONES</td>
                      <td>WBE</td>
                      <td>SUBESTACIÓN DESTINO</td>
                      <td>ESTATUS</td>
                      <td>PROYECTO WBE</td>
                      <td>CANTIDAD EXISTENTE MRO 43897</td>
                      <td>BARCODE</td>
                      <td>CORREO FUNCIONAL</td>
                      <td>ID PEDIDO</td>
                  </tr>
              <tr>
 ... and so on..
```

But the result on draft on gmail trough console o inspector is

```js
<table><tbody><tr><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td></tr><tr><td>PM</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>FUNCIONAL </td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>TIPO</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>PROYECTO</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>E4E</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>SAP</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td><span zeum4c16="PR_1_0" data-ddnwab="PR_1_0" aria-invalid="spelling" class="LI ng">DESCRIPCION</span></td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>UN</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>CANTIDAD</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>OBSERVACIONES</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>WBE</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>SUBESTACIÓN DESTINO</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>ESTATUS</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>PROYECTO WBE</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>CANTIDAD EXISTENTE MRO 43897</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>BARCODE</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>CORREO FUNCIONAL</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td><td>ID PEDIDO</td><td>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </td></tr><tr><td>
```

And table come with all of this spaces between every columns and rows.

ps. i don't wanna use convertRange2html() because i want display 2 tables and control the way of display, and the second is a transformation from first, and no interested on format from gsheets.

Thank you for all advice you can give me.

Comment: What is `convertRange2html()`?

Comment: @Tanike is the use of a library on AppsScript that people use for get the format of Gsheet and convert directly on html, however in my code gets error, and i dont wanna use [link](https://www.excell-en.com/google-sheets-macro-scheduling-tutorial)

Comment: Could this be coming from the template `'Correo'`? I could made simple HTML tables for a Gmail without the HTMLService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i find was modify Correo.html to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div>
<body>
<table>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
<tr>
<? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
<td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
<? } ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Is mean, without "spaces" in the code, so in this way the table get correctly constructed